# deserialize a dynamic json object to a class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, json-deserialization

I'm working with an external API to get some product information, the end points return some data in a static structure and others in dynamic depending on the product I'm inquiring.

For example if I'm requesting data for a soap I get the following JSON:

```json
    { "id": 4623,
      "brand": "Fa",
      "category": "Cleansing/Washing/Soap – Body",
      "photos": {
        "name": "Photos",
        "value": [        "https//test.com/1jpg"
        ]
      },
      "productname": {
        "name": "Product Name",
        "value": "Fa Shower Cream Yoghurt Vanilla Honey"
      },
      "warningstatement": {
        "name": "Warning Statement",
        "value": "Avoid contact with eyes."
      },
      "consumerusageinstructions": {
        "name": "Consumer Usage Instructions",
        "value": "Apply directly on skin."
      
    }
```

and if I'm inquiring about a cheese I get the following JSON:

```json
     {
      "id": 10838,
      "brand": "Domty",
      "category": "Cheese",
      
      "photos": {
        "name": "Photos",
        "value": [ "https://test.com/2.jpg"
        ]
      },
      "productname": {
        "name": "Product Name",
        "value": "Domty White Low Salt Cheese"
      },
      "description": {
        "name": "1312",
        "value": "Highest premium quality"
      },
      "netcontent": {
        "name": "Net Content",
        "value": "900 gm"
      }
```

and it goes on for every product they offer. I've no problem deserializing the static data like photos array, product name, brand, and id since they are applicable to every product, but the other dynamic properties are the ones I'm concerned about. Is there a way to deserialize to a class like this:

```cs
public class Info {
    property string key { get; set;} // to hold description, consumerusageinstructions or what every key
    property string name { get; set;}
    property string value { get; set;}
}
```

and then add a collection of the class info to my product model?

Comment: Did you try to special paste as Json classes?

Comment: yes for most of them and every product have different properties , and some properties will be changed over time as they add more products , i don't want to change my code every time they add or  update a product , think of the odes milk , chees, soap, tobaccos, tvs , mobiles  , computers all have different properties , that's why i want to store them as a collection of (key,name,value)

Comment: ... you can always deserialize json to `dynamic` or `Dictionary<string, object>` or just to `JObject` / `JsonObject` ... it really depends on later use

Comment: I've thought about using Dictionary<string,DataClass> but i can not deserialize the json into the Dictionary property in my ProductModel class

Comment: Then you have to write custom JsonConverter

Comment: [you may also use `JsonExtensionDataAttribute`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tLmFmP) ... so you may have some common properties and other in fx `IDictionary<string, NamedValue> Values` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is just to parse the Json and look at the actual entities: this example uses Json.Net:

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
var properties = parsed.Children().Cast<JProperty>();
foreach (var property in properties) {
    
    // an alternative here would be to just have a list of names to ignore
    if (!(property.Value is JObject jObject)) {
        // skip the simple property/value pairs
        continue;
    }

    if (property.Name == "productname") {
        // skip product name
        continue;
    }

    if (property.Value["value"] is JArray) {
        // skip photos
        continue;
    }

    // Add to ProductModel instance
    Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name} => {property.Value["name"]} = {property.Value["value"]}");

}
```

Outputs:

> warningstatement => Warning Statement = Avoid contact with eyes.
> consumerusageinstructions => Consumer Usage Instructions = Apply directly on skin.

> description => 1312 = Highest premium quality
> netcontent => Net Content = 900 gm